# Remove a node in unordered_map based on the address fof a node

Tags: c++

Given a unordered_map object, wonder if it's possible to erase a node by the reference (or address) of a node.  In another word, in the following code snippet, wonder if it's possible to remove the node for "UK" by the address of variable x or something similar.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,int> mymap;

// populating container:
mymap["US"] = 10;
mymap["UK"] = 9;
mymap["US"] ++;
mymap["France"] = 8;
int &x = mymap["UK"];
```

This is useful in an app, where I need to keep track of the frequencies of various strings in a time interval (say, the last 3 hours). The strings can have size from a few bytes to thousands of bytes.  Each time a string expires (based on its arrival time and size of time interval), I will reduce the frequency for this string. If the frequency is 0, I will need to remove the node for the string. Don't want to allocate space to store the strings in timer queue, that would be a waste of space.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: You could store shared_ptr<string> objects instead of plain strings, that way you could store the same string in both the unordered_map and the timer queue, and there would still be only one copy of each string in memory.

Answer (score 2):

`unordered_map` supports two `erase` overloads:

- by key
- by iterator

There is no such *"erase through address of mapped value"*. Basically you have two ways of doing it:

```
int main() {
    unordered_map<string, int> data;

    data["UK"] = 10;
    data["UK"]++;
    data["US"] = 8;

    cout << data.size() << endl;
    auto it = data.find("UK");
    data.erase(it);
    cout << data.size() << endl;
    data.erase("US");
    cout << data.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Using the iterator is more efficent because you can obtain the value (through `second` member) and together erase it without the need to do two lookups.

By your comment you can't take the address of an iterator which is obtained by value on a local variable. That would yield a local address in any case, but the standard guarantees you that iterators in an `unordered_map` are not invalidated upon insertion and on delete only the affected one is invalidated, so storing them somewhere is allowed, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
using map_type = unordered_map<string, int>;

map_type data;
vector<map_type::iterator> timer_queue;

void timeTick()
{
  for_each(begin(timer_queue), end(timer_queue), [](map_type::iterator& it) {
    --it->second;

    if (it->second == 0)
    {
      cout << "pair " << it->first << " has expired" << endl;
      data.erase(it);
      cout << "map size: " << data.size() << endl;
    }
  });
}

template<typename... Args> void addElement(Args... args)
{
  auto it = get<0>(data.emplace(args...));
  timer_queue.push_back(it);
}

int main() {

  addElement("IT", 5);
  addElement("US", 10);
  addElement("UK", 8);

  while (!data.empty())
  {
    cout << "time tick" << endl;
    timeTick();
  }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet.  I need to keep a timer queue, for each timer, I will need to have some info to locate the node in the map. I could use string, but it's too wasteful, that's why I thought I may keep the address of the node.   I need to convert the iterator in a 8 byte field of a structure, so I need the following conversion:  `std::unordered_map<std::string,int>::const_iterator it = mymap.find("UK");
 void *x = (void *)it;`, but it failed in compiling.  Any idea how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the value itself, but you *can* use `std::map::find` to get an iterator to the interesting item in the map and delete the iterator's key/value pair directly.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this for production code, but if you are okay with making the assumption that your STL's implementation of unordered_map is storing keys and values together in a struct, and that therefore the memory locations of the key and value in a given key/value pair will always be at a fixed offset from each other, you could use the GetKeyFromValue() function below to retrieve the key associated with your reference-to-a-value.  Then you could use that pass that key in to erase() or whatever, as usual.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

/** Given a reference to a value in (map), returns a reference to the associated key.
  * @param map Reference to the unordered_map object.
  * @param value Reference to a value in (map).  If this reference is to some object that is
  *              not actually stored in (map), then this function's behavior is undefined, so be careful!
  * @returns A reference to the key associated with (value).
  */
template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType> const KeyType & GetKeyFromValue(const unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType> & map, const ValueType & value)
{
   if (map.size() == 0) throw invalid_argument("Called GetKeyFromValue() on an empty map!?");

   auto it = map.begin();
   const KeyType   * firstKey = &it->first;
   const ValueType * firstVal = &it->second;

   const char * cFirstKey = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(firstKey);
   const char * cFirstVal = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(firstVal);
   ptrdiff_t diff = cFirstVal-cFirstKey;

   const char * cUserVal = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&value);
   cUserVal -= diff;
   return *(reinterpret_cast<const KeyType *>(cUserVal));
}

// Quick unit test for the above
int main(int, char **)
{
   unordered_map<string, int> mymap;
   mymap["US"] = 10;
   mymap["UK"] = 9;
   mymap["US"]++;
   mymap["France"]=8;

   int & x = mymap["UK"];
   const string & uk = GetKeyFromValue(mymap, x);
   cout << "keyForX=[" << uk << "]" << endl;

   int & y = mymap["France"];
   const string & france = GetKeyFromValue(mymap, y);
   cout << "keyForY=[" << france << "]" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jeremy-friesner for the example code,  that's really a big assumption! I am thinking of storing the iterator (8 bytes).

Comment: Note that the iterator will become invalid whenever the unordered_map is modified; dunno if that will be a problem for you or not.  (Then again, a held reference-to-a-value might become invalid when the unordered_map is modified also)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, you are right, reference to an iterator may not be valid. Seems that it's real hard to come up with a (memory-wise) optimal solution for the tracking of frequencies of strings in a time-interval.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: actually that's not true at all. As specified at §23.2.4.9 of C++11 standard you have that *The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.*. So storing a reference to an iterator is perfectly valid until you invalidate it, by removing the element from the map.

Comment: Interesting -- if inserting an item causes the unordered_map to have to resize itself larger, I wonder how the iterators remain valid after their underlying data items have been copied-and-then-deleted?